# MYSQL - Retrieving weeks in a month

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to list all weeks in a month, (e.g., 2015-02-01 and 2015-02-28) in the following format: (week yyyy-mm-dd to week yyyy-mm-dd etc.)

[image]

Tried using `WEEK` e.g., SELECT WEEK(2015-02-01) - WEEK(2015-02-28); but this just gave me the number of numbers in the month - 4.

What is the proper MYSQL statement to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`DATE_FORMAT` should work, have you tried it that way :

```
select date_format(your_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
from yourTable;
```

If your field is a string you could also use `str_to_date`

```
select str_to_date(your_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
from yourTable;
```

Comment: How does this calculate the weeks in the month? I understand it's formatting the date but I'm at a loss on how to calculate the weeks in the month.